# EB Garamond: no bullet point in itemize list

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, itemize, ebgaramond

I installed the EB Garamond fonts as follows:

1. From the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond), I went to the [Release page](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/releases) and downloaded lastest nightly release, which is dated 13th March 2023 and corresponds to commit [d04d0f9](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/commit/d04d0f9da5adad27ff0e5947807b80cfe13dc477)
2. I decompressed the zip files and copied OTF files over:
   `cp *.otf ~/.local/share/fonts`
3. I run `fc-cache --really-force --verbose`
4. I checked with `fc-match "EB Garamond"`, which returned `EBGaramond08-Regular.otf: "EB Garamond" "08 Regular"`

I use Arch Linux and my xelatex version is:

```
❯ xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
Copyright 2023 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 73.2; using 73.2
Compiled with zlib version 1.3; using 1.3
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.13.1; using 2.13.1
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.14; using 1.3.14
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 8.1.1; using 8.1.1
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.40; using 1.6.40
Compiled with pplib version v2.05 less toxic i hope
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.14.2; using 2.14.2
```

My problem is that bullet points don't show up in itemized lists:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

Hello

\begin{itemize}
    \item Hi
    \item Hello
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

1. Why is that?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Could it be that the itemize uses math for bullets? What if you use `\setmathfont` as well? (Just a guess.)

Comment: @mickep if it would use math it wouldn't be missing (unless something is really broken).

Comment: Does `\def\mymathbullet{$\bullet$}\let\textbullet\mymathbullet` work? (Thanks to Ulrike's hint.)

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when did you last update it? The reason I ask is that am unable to reproduce the issue you report with MacTeX2023 (all updates applied)

Comment: @Mico did you compile fonts from the repository? Because I didn't find any ttf/otf in it. Maybe the font which OP is using is work-in-progress

Comment: @Niranjan - Which repository? I have a full version of MacTeX, which contains its own copy of the EB Garamond font files.

Comment: @Mico Exactly, there is a chance that the fonts compiled from the GitHub repository (which OP has given in the question) are different from the ones that come in the TeX installation.

Comment: "This project is under heavy development. Don’t expect the fonts to be anywhere near to ready or perfect." (-- from the download page of that project)

Comment: @Niranjan - Thanks. So the answer should be "what are you doing relying on the GitHub site? Why aren't you using the font that's provided by the TeX distribution?" :-)

Comment: @Mico well ... :-)

Comment: I just checked the latest version of these fonts from [here](https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads/). Tested the code with `EBGaramond12-Regular.otf`, [it works](https://imgur.com/aemuRws.png). [Works](https://imgur.com/NidZFDp.png) with `EBGaramond12-Regular.ttf` also. Tried with both the engines. Something other than this is wrong with OPs code.

Comment: @Mico if you can name the package, then OP may try installing that specific package with the package manager and get the correct fonts.

Comment: @Niranjan - The OP might skip loading the `fontspec` package and issuing a `\setmainfont` directive and, instead, try loading the `ebgaramond` package. This package contains code for XeLaTeX- and LuaLaTeX-specific font loading procedures. The OP may also want to de-install the experimental stuff he/she obtained from GitHub.

Comment: @Niranjan In the bitbucket repo you linked to the latest release seems to be dated 2014. On [GitHub Release page](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/releases) the latest release is dated march 2023. The username is "georgd" in both cases, although of course I cannot know whether it corresponds to the same person. I used the GitHub release page. I'll update my question once I figured out whether I copied OTF or TTF files over.

Comment: An edit to the original question specifies the installation procedure I followed and the XeLaTeX version I have

Comment: The package `ebgaramond` works, thanks for the suggestion! But I'll keep my question out of curiosity (and maybe it will happen with other fonts as well)

Comment: @robertspierre Ah! I reached that repository only because the official site took me there. So on the GitHub repo, I found [this](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/) link to the website of the font. It has a page called [development/download](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/download.html). It has a section called "Downloading and using this font" which I expected to have the most perfect information. It had the line which I quoted as well as the BitBucket link.

Comment: Also, now I finally could [reproduce](https://imgur.com/dFpi8Rs.png) your issue!! Thanks for the research and providing step-by-step information. The best place to report is obviously https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/issues. By this I mean, it's not LaTeX, it's your font.

Comment: @Niranjan and what's wrong with my font?

Comment: @robertspierre Sorry, really not a font-expert. Also, it would be considered off-topic here as far as I know.

Comment: To the extent that it can be answered by pointing out what is needed for a font to render a bullet point in an itemize environment (e.g. which codepoint), I think it is in scope